# Convert substr output using awk into a numerical value

Tags: awk, grep

When I use:

```
$grep ENMAX filename
```

I get the output as:

```
ENMAX  =  240.300; ENMIN  =  180.225 eV
```

If if use:

```
E=`grep ENMAX POTCAR |awk '{print substr($3,1,7)}'`
```

I am unable to use the value of `E` in an expression or for calculation say `E*0.7`

Can you help me convert the (apparently) string output to a numerical value?

Comment: How are you trying to perform this "expression"?  Also do you need to keep the zero decimal places of the number?  You could avoid the `substr` call by just doing `awk '{print $3/1}'` to get rid of the `;` but it would output `240.3`.

Comment: This works for me: `bc <<< "$(echo 'ENMAX  =  240.300; ENMIN  =  180.225 eV' | awk '{print $3/1}')*0.7"`.  However if you are trying to use shell arithmetic it does not support floating point.  Also awk can perform the arithmetic itself so you could just do: `echo 'ENMAX  =  240.300; ENMIN  =  180.225 eV' | awk '{print $3*0.7}'`

Comment: That is so cool & quick. Thanks Jesse! The option to print $#/1 still gives a string but the awk arithmetic does the job. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: The shell doesn't really have any concept of data types as you would expect from other languages so, with a few exceptions, everything in the shell is a string.  The data being a string wouldn't make you unable to perform arithmetic with it, the method you were using to perform said arithmetic was likely the issue but I can't know what that method is from your question.

Comment: I tried Elo= `expr E * 0.7` and Ehi=`expr E * 1.3`. Both obviously didn't work because the E (from the original qn) was a string. [*Edit on my prev ans. print $3/1 still gives a string]

Comment: The reason they didn't work is because the shell doesn't handle floating point arithmetic.  It being a string had nothing to do with it.  All variables are strings to the shell* (sort of).